# How to center a view horizontally in a Xamarin.Forms RelativeLayout?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, view, centering

I want to center a label horizontally in a `RelativeLayout` in `Xamarin.Forms`. I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
var label = new Label {HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center};

var rl = new RelativeLayout();

rl.Children.Add(label, Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => parent.Width / 2 - label.Width / 2));
```

I want to place a second label on the right of my label while the first label is centered horizontally. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are doing **RelativeLayouts** you have **Constraints** that you can specify.

To achieve what you are aiming to do, you need to use a **RelativeToParent** **Constraint** first, and then a **RelativeToView** **Constraint** for the 2nd *label* that is attached to the right of the first *view*.

The first *view* will then be centered horizontally across the whole page, with the 2nd *label* attached **relative** to the first *view* afterwards.

The following example shows this:-

```
RelativeLayout objRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();

Label objLabel1 = new Label();
objLabel1.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
objLabel1.Text = "This is a label";
objLabel1.WidthRequest = 300;
objRelativeLayout.Children.Add(objLabel1,
    xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
    {
        return ((parent.Width - objLabel1.Width) / 2);
    }));

Label objLabel2 = new Label();
objLabel2.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
objLabel2.Text = "Hi";
objLabel2.WidthRequest = 100;
objRelativeLayout.Children.Add(objLabel2,
    xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToView(objLabel1,
    new Func<RelativeLayout, View, double>((pobjRelativeLayout, pobjView) =>
    {
        return pobjView.X + pobjView.Width;
    })));

this.Content = objRelativeLayout;
```

**Update 1:-**

If you don't want to use a specified **Width** or the contents are of an unknown size then you will have to trigger a *re-layout* via calling **ForceLayout** on the **RelativeLayout** when the *view(s)* need to be repositioned according to the **Constraints** you have defined.

The updated example below illustrates this:-

```
StackLayout objStackLayout = new StackLayout()
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
};

RelativeLayout objRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout();
objStackLayout.Children.Add(objRelativeLayout);

Label objLabel1 = new Label();
objLabel1.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
objLabel1.Text = "This is a label";
objLabel1.SizeChanged += ((o2, e2) =>
{
    objRelativeLayout.ForceLayout();
});
objRelativeLayout.Children.Add(objLabel1,
    xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
    {
        return ((parent.Width - objLabel1.Width) / 2);
    }));

Label objLabel2 = new Label();
objLabel2.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
objLabel2.Text = "Hi";
objRelativeLayout.Children.Add(objLabel2,
    xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToView(objLabel1,
    new Func<RelativeLayout, View, double>((pobjRelativeLayout, pobjView) =>
    {
        return pobjView.X + pobjView.Width;
    })));

Button objButton1 = new Button();
objButton1.Text = "Test1";
objButton1.Clicked += ((o2, e2) =>
    {
        objLabel1.Text = "This is some other label text";
    });
objStackLayout.Children.Add(objButton1);

this.Content = objStackLayout;
```

Comment: This only works when ´objLabel1´ has a set WidthRequest. In my case this doesn't work because the text of the first label changes dynamically. Is there a way to achieve my goal without giving the first label a WidthRequest?

Comment: I've updated my answer with more info (see Update 1)

Comment: Thanks for this. Xamarin layouts are so kludgey.